# I can serialize 167 records only. Any other throws An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight, serialization

I am completely exhausted a to be honest, I really don't know, what to do. I am developing Silverlight application using Silverlight wcf. My webconfig looks like this:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
<source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information,Error,ActivityTracing"     propagateActivity="true" >
<listeners>
<add name="xml" />
</listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="CardSpace">
            <listeners>
                <add name="xml" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.IO.Log">
            <listeners>
                <add name="xml" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.Runtime.Serialization" switchValue="Information,Error,ActivityTracing">
            <listeners >
                <add name="xml" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.IdentityModel">
            <listeners>
                <add name="xml" />
            </listeners>
        </source>

        <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
            <listeners>
                <add name="xml"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="myUserTraceSource"
                switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
            <listeners>
                <add name="xml"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="xml"
             type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                   initializeData="e:\Traces.svclog"

             />
    </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>


<system.serviceModel>

    <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging
 logEntireMessage="true"
 logMalformedMessages="true"
 logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
 logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
 maxMessagesToLog="3000"
  maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2147483647"
 />

    </diagnostics>

    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ServicesBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                 maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>


    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="SUS.Web.Services.BaseService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServicesBinding"
             contract="SUS.Web.Services.BaseService" />
        </service>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="SUS.Web.Services.NuggetServices">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServicesBinding"
             contract="SUS.Web.Services.NuggetServices" />
        </service>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="SUS.Web.Services.WorkspaceServices">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServicesBinding"
             contract="SUS.Web.Services.WorkspaceServices" />
        </service>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="SUS.Web.Services.GeneralTemplateService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServicesBinding"
             contract="SUS.Web.Services.GeneralTemplateService" />
        </service>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="SUS.Web.Services.QueryService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServicesBinding"
             contract="SUS.Web.Services.QueryService" />

        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I am sharing assemblies between server and Silverlight project so I can send classes between them. Server generates 250 objects. I can send them in a collection of 167 max. I can choose any 167 objects of VmNugget from these 250 it is not the problem of any concrete object. My ViewModels are pretty complex, can contain each other and one can be ancestor of another one. MY classes are decorated with [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes. Do you have any tips how could I inspect the process during serialization? MY webService is decorated this way:

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(VmCulture))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(VmNugget))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(VmDesignedNugget))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(VmDesigner))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(OperationLog))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(OperationLog))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(VmFile))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(VmQuery))]
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class QueryService : BaseService
```

Interesting thing:

I have removed all constructor from properties like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<VmNugget> my;
[DataMember]
public ObservableCollection<VmNugget> My
get{
/* commented
if (this.my == null)
 this.my = new ObservableCollection<VmNugget>();
*/ 
return this.my;
}
```

I have tried to put more than 167 empty objects to returned collection and I can NOT serialized them and send to the client. These objects should be empty (uninitialized).

I am sending it using VmQuery class with a OBservableCollection  in Rows property.

Thank you very much.

Tomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you do not have an infinite loop or infinite recursion.
Too many method calls is often indicative of a very deep or unbounded recursion.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

`My ViewModels are pretty complex, can contain each other and one can be ancestor of another one.`

This is likely where your problem lies.  I suspect you have a couple of objects that have a circular reference between them, and that the serialiser is overflowing.  One way to check this would be to try to serialise each object (and it's children) one at a time.  I would bet that one of them (or possibly more) will exhibit the behaviour you described.

Consider serialising a reference to child objects by ID rather than by the full object itself.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much. I have finally found it. In one property I have used OBservableCollection descendant. This class is adding a wonderful ability to remember reference to the parent collection to each of the contained object. :-) Solved and I am still alive. The world is so pretty.